# Java 8 "var" equivalent

Tags: java-8, ringcentral

I'm working on a tutorial in RingCentral, and it uses var. I'm still on java 8. Anyone know what to put here instead?

```
package Call_RingOut;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.ringcentral.*;
import com.ringcentral.definitions.*;


public class Call_RingOut {
static String RECIPIENT_NUMBER = "<ENTER PHONE NUMBER>";

static String RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID = "<ENTER CLIENT ID>";
static String RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET = "<ENTER CLIENT SECRET>";
static String RINGCENTRAL_SERVER = "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com";

static String RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME = "<YOUR ACCOUNT PHONE NUMBER>";
static String RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD = "<YOUR ACCOUNT PASSWORD>";
static String RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION = "<YOUR EXTENSION, PROBABLY '101'>";

static RestClient restClient;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var obj = new Call_RingOut();
    try {
      restClient = new RestClient(RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID, RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET, RINGCENTRAL_SERVER);
      restClient.authorize(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME, RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION, RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD);
      obj.call_ringout()();
    } catch (RestException | IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void call_ringout() throws RestException, IOException {
    MakeRingOutRequest requestBody = new MakeRingOutRequest();
    requestBody.from(new MakeRingOutCallerInfoRequestFrom().phoneNumber(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME));
    requestBody.to(new MakeRingOutCallerInfoRequestTo().phoneNumber(RECIPIENT_NUMBER));
    requestBody.playPrompt = false;

    var response = restClient.restapi().account().extension().ringout().post(requestBody);
    System.out.println("Call Placed. Call status: " + response.status.callStatus);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no `var` equivalent in Java 8 all variable must have a type they cannot be inferred. In `var obj = new Call_RingOut();` you can replace `var` with `Call_RingOut`. In the other one your code doesn't have enough info, but your IDE will probably tell you what the `post` method returns.

Comment: Thanks DCTID, I knew there wasn't a direct equivalent. That worked. Turns out I don't need the response, so I ended up calling the method and ignoring the response.

Comment: `Object` and then cast explicitly xd

Comment: In every IDE, you can simply remove the `var`, followed by accepting the IDE’s first suggestion, which will let the IDE insert the correct variable type.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Lombok to your project, you can use [`var` in Java 8](https://projectlombok.org/features/var). The implementation is not the same but for your purposes, that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `var` with `GetRingOutStatusResponse`, which is the class of the return value of the final message, `post()`.

```java
GetRingOutStatusResponse response = restClient.restapi().account().extension().ringout().post(requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below

`Call_RingOut obj = new Call_RingOut();`

`GetRingOutStatusResponse response = restClient.restapi().account().extension().ringout().post(requestBody);`

Answer (score 0):

There is RingCentral SDK and can find out the object name from the Java SDK sample codes here:
https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java/blob/master/samples.md

`GetRingOutStatusResponse` will be the response object returned from the ringout API

Here is the reference: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ringcentral/definitions/GetRingOutStatusResponse.java

Try something as follow, method call will be Post:

```
Call_RingOut obj = new Call_RingOut();
obj.call_ringout();   

GetRingOutStatusResponse response = restClient.restapi().account().extension().ringout().post(requestBody);
```